# Отображение кнопки в IE8

Tags: css, css3

Имеется кнопка со стелкой, подскажите, как сделать чтобы стрелка отображалась в IE8 и старше

```css
.multiplay {
 display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
 color: #fff;
 border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px; 
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;  
 background: rgb(71,164,26);
 border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(23, 103, 6, 0.9), rgba(22, 80, 7, 0.92)) repeat scroll 0 0;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-right: none;
 position: relative;
}
.multiplay:after, .multiplay:before {
 left: 100%;
 top: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
}
.multiplay:after {
 border-width: 23px;
 margin-top: -23px;
 margin-left: -4px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgb(71,164,26);
 line-height: 0px;
}
.multiplay:before {
 border-color: rgba(74, 128, 60, 0);
 border-left-color: rgb(71,164,26);
 border-width: 23px;
 margin-top: -23px;
 margin-left: -4px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="multiplay button">Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: Если вам нужен IE8, то не насилуйте CSS, просто используйте картинки.

Comment: @Discord тоесть для IE решения на css нет? Хотя бы для последних версий. Простое хотелось бы использовать кучу картинок для разных состояний

Comment: IE8 не умеет модных бордеров, которыми всё это безобразие рисуется. Вы можете поиграться со всякими CSS3Pie и прочими подобными поделками, но у них куча ограничений, проблем, тормозов и прочего. Во времена IE8 все использовали картинки, и это самый адекватный способ.